# Can the user who elects to have the SE bot autogenerate a chatroom have ownership of said room?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Often I find that a topic goes beyond a straightforward answer to a question, and a lot of discussion is carried out in comments regardless of the *'comments are for asking for clarification'* rule of thumb.
Eventually someone will get a prompt (with a link) to move the discussion to chat.
[image]

If they click the provided link *(blue highlight)* a chatroom is generated, but they do not have ownership.
**EDIT: The autogenerated title is Discussion between COMMENTER and OP.**

Shouldn't the person who acted upon the prompt be able to change the title?  In an attempt to be more democratic and not scrub others posts and not single out two single individuals?

There are several ideas related to this, but being my first feature request, I will forego those for now.

Comment: What would be a benefit?

Comment: @Gimby Because then the user who clicks the button can move all the comments they don't like somewhere else, obviously :p

Comment: @GWarner you mentioned some points under [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408441/11573842) answer of yours... consider adding those into this post too...

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 Sticking with 'one question at a time'  is the first thing I learned about SE. Wouldn't that be the case here?

Comment: You should not ask multiple questions as a time. However, if you have multiple justifications to offer in favor of a feature request, that’s always useful to include. I hope that makes sense. For what it’s worth, your idea is, on-face, a sensible one. The reason I would oppose it would be strictly because of moderation-related issues, as noted by one of the answers already. But that doesn’t mean there can’t still be some improvements to the workings of this feature. It’s never gotten much love. It’s always just been a place to dump unwanted overflow comments.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for the feedback. It was both suggested I create a NEW post with the feature request I actually had meant. And then another said I shouldn't and just edit this question, despite all the answers and comments (which could become meaningless after an edit). So I am almost decided to not bother suggesting more improvements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Imagine this scenario:

Two users are trying to settle a disagreement about the provided solution. The system offers to create a chatroom. The dispute moves on in the now created chatroom. After a few exchanges the user that also got RO-ship gets upset and decide to kick-mute the user. The other user returns, confused what just happened, get kicked again and if they manage once more they just chat banned a user for 30 minutes.

They can also move messages to other rooms, making the transcript hard to follow.

I don't think that rooms that are "linked" to a Q/A should have room owners to simply prevent that the few that can't control themselves make chat an insecure place for those that observe that behavior.

We can't have nice things.

Comment: I do note that the trigger for getting that chat room link offered does require that only two users go back-and-forth 4 or 5 times in comments. From that perspective it does make sense the room gets created with those two users in mind

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I see a point.

The objective of moving comment chains to chat is to get them out of comment chains and let involved or interested parties chat about the subject at hand in a temporal fashion.

It's not intended to be a proper chat room on its own.

Comment: The autogeneration scrubs out any comments that are not the commenter or the OPs and only uses comments from that answer. I am questioning it cutting out others input. And placing a title that excludes them, despite being a public room.

Answer (score 4):

I think that giving such rooms an owner would *not* be a good idea. Many people don't like to use those rooms. We often see new comments posted outside the room. Making the room less democratic by giving the creator (or the author of the post its attached to) room owner privileges would likely be more of a discouragement to use the room.

Comment: What about just changing the title then. To keep it democratic, Change it to Discussion about (title of Q or A where the commenter autogenerated room, rather then Discussion between Commenter and OP?

Comment: @GWarner I agree that the current naming scheme is sub-optimal. However, naming it based on the question title (answers don't have titles) wouldn't be much of an improvement, since a question page can spawn multiple chat rooms. And question titles can be edited at any time. OTOH, I guess it wouldn't hurt to allow the room creator & / or post author to name the room.

Comment: So do I follow procedure and post a new focused question. Or will this question be closed because your suggestion " allow the room creator & / or post author to name the room." doesn't answer the question whether that was the real issue or not?

Comment: @GWarner I don't think you need a new question. Just allow some time for people to respond to this one.

Comment: IMHO Coders can be a difficult bunch to work with anyway. Too laser focused and can't see around corners. Question is closed with one more DV anyway. They are already moving on.

Comment: This question currently has no close votes. The downvotes probably just indicate that people don't think your request is a good idea, not that they think the question itself is a bad one. That's just how the meta sites work.

Comment: @GWarner - You should edit your question.  You should absolutely NOT submit a new question once this question is closed (if that even happens)